# How to write large volumes of unique data to Postgres without storing it all in memory

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a Spring Boot application that generates images. I'm trying to scale it to the point it can generate an unlimited number of images.

When an image is generated I create a hash using `MurmurHash3` of the base64 encoded values of the image, this is then added to an object as a `@Lob` value. The hash is how I consider images to be unique, the images are then pushed into Postgres.

So far everything is fine and this creates ~1,000 images in a few seconds without problem. Where I'm having issues is say I want to create 100,000+ images.

When the images are generated there is a pretty good chance of duplicates, so what I thought was a good idea would be to create 'chunks' of images using a `HashSet` to hopefully rule out duplicates at least within the specific 'chunk'

```
public class CreateImages {
    //...

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void process() {
        while (repository.count() < 100_000) {
            createChunk();
        }
    }

    private void createChunk() {

        Set<TokenUri> result = new HashSet<>();

        while (result.size() < 1000) {
            final ImageWrapper imageWrapper = svgService.create(-1); 

            result.add(TokenUri.builder()
                    .hash(imageWrapper.hash())
                    .data(encodeService.encode(imageWrapper))
                    .build());
        }

        try {
            repository.saveAll(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to save chunk {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        log.info("Created {} images", repository.count());
    }
}
```

Not worrying about time taken here to create the images (it's all single threaded) this will do what I expect, each chunk doesn't contain duplicates, however more than likely it will contain duplicates when compared to previously generated chunks.

So to try and solve that I added a `@Column(unique = true)` annotation to each `hash` row being saved. Thinking Postgres will reject duplicates, but allow 'non-duplicates' to be saved.

What seems to happen though is the batch write fails due to not satisfying the condition and doesn't seem to move past it.

```
2022-01-02 15:38:56.071 ERROR 19292 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_90jgw9r7w8bhtgw17fmi79j0w"
  Detail: Key (hash)=(1625765490) already exists.
```

Even when attempting to catch those with a generic `Exception` either I'm not handling it correctly, or it doesn't do what I expect.

Even this feels rather hackey and not a correct solution.

So, tl:dr - How can I generate an unknown (assume millions) of unique objects, (without keeping them all in memory to check for uniqueness) and safely store those into Postgres?

Is there some standard pattern for this kind of thing?

Comment: You can try to append `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` to the `insert` statement used in saveAll(xxx) to skip duplicates without facing that constraint violation error

Comment: Add a UNIQUE constraint in Postgres, ignore the exception that is thrown when it's violated.

Comment: "Even when attempting to catch those with a generic Exception either I'm not handling it correctly, or it doesn't do what I expect."  You should show us the parts of the code that have the problem rather than the parts that don't.

Comment: @jjanes read it again and check the try/catch block.

Comment: Thanks @dshelya and Alexey Veleshko it's what I had ended up doing, was just hoping for some alternative solution as this seems to just mask the problem but this seems to be what people recommend...

Comment: Of course it ignores entire chunks where you currently have it.  Did you try moving it down into saveAll?  Or parse the error message, remove the offender, and retry?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible solution. You save only hash property in a Set and in that way you can have unique hash across chunks and also it's memory efficient because you are saving only a String and not an object with all properties. You also need to override hashCode and equals methods in TokenUri (to use hash property) because otherwise `Set<TokenUri>` doesn't work.

```
public class CreateImages {
    //...

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void process() {
        Set<String> hashCodesOfSavedImages = new HashSet<>();
        while (hashCodesOfSavedImages.size() < 100_000) {
            hashCodesOfSavedImages.addAll(createChunkOfImages(hashCodesOfSavedImages, 1000));
        }
        
    }

    private Set<String> createChunkOfImages(Set<String> hashCodesOfSavedImages, int chunkSize) {

        Set<TokenUri> chunkOfImages = new HashSet<>();

        while (chunkOfImages.size() < chunkSize) {
            final ImageWrapper imageWrapper = svgService.create(-1);

            // O(1) time complexity (contains)
            if (!hashCodesOfSavedImages.contains(imageWrapper.hash())) {
                chunkOfImages.add(TokenUri.builder()
                    .hash(imageWrapper.hash())
                    .data(encodeService.encode(imageWrapper))
                    .build());
            }
        }

        repository.saveAll(chunkOfImages);

        return chunkOfImages.stream().map(TokenUri::hash).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Comment: While this will reduce the memory consumption of each chunk, it still won't scale as eventually `hashCodesOfSavedImages` will consume more memory than allocated to the JVM